# Get the location of pink spot irrespective of scroll on UIButton touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cgpoint

[image]

I have a button inside my scrollview, I want to locate the x,y position(marked as a pink dot in the image) and assign it to my variables whenever I click on any part of the button irrespective of the scroll. ***Below code will give me the touch location irrespective of scroll, similarly is there generalized code to get the location of pink spot in the image irrespective of scrolling?***

```
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:sender];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint locationX = [touch locationInView:sender];

     NSLog(@"Location: %f, %f", location.x, location.y);
```

Comment: Can't you use the button's frame? The position will just be `{origin.x, origin.y + size.height}`.

Comment: What about subtracting myScrollView.contentOffset from your point coordinates?

Comment: @guy kogus, that will not work if my button is near to bottom, for eg: if my view height is 700 and button height is 50, and my current button location is (10,500), so as per your calculation it would give me coordinates, (10,550) which would be out of the current scope of view.

Comment: No it wouldn't. The frame of a view is relative to its superview. As @verec mentioned, you could subtract the `contentOffset` to get the location of the point in the scrollView's superview's coordinate system.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the dot on the button or on the scroll view?

Comment: Its jst to denote, its on the button.